# AppStore ios version requires ipad media

Tags: ios, app-store

Hi I have an application on the app store already uploaded, the first version did not require images for ipad, i am trying to upload a new version and it requires ipad images, how can I specify that this app is not ment to be used on ipad?

**EDIT**: The app is built using react-native and expo

Answer (score 0):

You have to set it in the deployment info in Xcode.

[image]

Comment: the app is build using expo and react-native

Comment: I think you have something like app.json. 
In there is a property ```supportsTablet```.